# Bash Script To Find Debian Release Number from /etc/debian_version

Tags: bash, debian, awk, bash-script

The following is what I'm currently using for testing the version of Debian. Instead of doing it this way, can I make it more succinct?

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=NONE
if [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.3' ]; then
  VERSION=7
elif [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.2' ]; then
  VERSION=7
elif [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.1' ]; then
  VERSION=7
elif [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.0' ]; then
  VERSION=7
fi
```

I know it's not the most attractive way of doing this. What I want, is to understand how to use the file at `/etc/debian_version` to read the version number before the `.` and ignore the number after.

I tried using

```
if [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.*' ]; then
```

and I also tried

```
if [ $(cat /etc/debian_version) == '7.2|7.1|7.0' ]; then
```

But neither of these worked for me. I want to future proof my script so that if Debian 7.4 gets released, then I won't have to go back over all the scripts that rely on this and alter them

I am also aware of the `lsb_release -a` showing me the relative information, I just don't know how to "cut" what I want from that and check that it is Debian 6 or 7. The original script, as you can imagine, is quite lengthy.

Any other posts you can point me to, would also be appreciated with using the method of "cutting" apart the response to only section out the part that I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want.  This one just removes the decimal point and everything after from the version number:

```
VERSION=$(sed 's/\..*//' /etc/debian_version)
```

`\..*` means a period (`\.`) followed by zero or more of any character (`.*`).  Thus, for `sed`, the expression `s/\..*//` means replace the period and all that follows with nothing.  The result of the `sed` command is saved in the environment variable `VERSION`.

The above eliminates the need for the if/then/elif/.../fi statements.  It will work with both bash and ordinary /bin/sh.

**MORE:**  `sed` is a stream editor: that means it reads lines from stdin, edits them as per instructions, and (typically) sends them to stdout.  In this case, we are giving it a "substitute" instruction.  For example, `s/foo/bar/` means find the first occurrence of foo and replace it with bar.  As a special case, `s/foo//` means replace `foo` with nothing.  In our case, we want to replace a period followed by any character with nothing.  Now, a period is "." except that `sed` normally treats a period to mean "any character".   So, we need to "escape" it by putting a backslash ahead of it.  When `sed` sees `\.`, it knows that we mean a literal period.  We also want to erase any characters following the period.  To represent "any character", we use a period `.` (no escape).  To be general, though, we want to delete all the characters following the period, regardless of how many there are.  So, while in `sed`'s language, a period means any character, the star means "any number of the preceding character" (which could be zero).  Thus period-star `.*` means zero or more of any character.  So, putting it all together, `s/\..*//` tells `sed` that if it finds a period, possibly followed by anything, then replace it with nothing.

Comment: Can this answer be elaborated for me. I understand what the `s/` part mean, but what about `\..*` ?

Comment: @DanijelJ I added some explanation.  It may overlap with what you already know but I figured that that was better than leaving out something that you didn't.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes, that explains a lot to me. I understood the `\.` I just couldn't understand the second `.`. Thank you for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution which uses bash, no external utilities, and is a single call

```
read -d . VERSION < /etc/debian_version
```

This reads `/etc/debian_version`, splits the input on the period (`.`), assigns everything before the period to `VERSION` and discards everything after.

---

```
IFS='.' read VERSION VERSION_MINOR < /etc/debian_version
```

This is slightly different in that it saves everything after the period in VERSION_MINOR

---

```
IFS='.' read -a VERSION < /etc/debian_version
```

This one is the most powerful in that it splits on the period, and assigns to the array `$VERSION`. If the version is `1.2.3` then `${VERSION[0]} == 1` `${VERSION[1]} == 2` and `${VERSION[2]} == 3`.

Comment: This is excellent! I've never seen read being used like this!

Answer (score 3):

```
case `cat /etc/debian_version` in
7*) VERSION=7;;
*) VERSION=NONE;;
esac
```

This can be extended to recognize more versions, of course.